# What is better to query elasticsearch from python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

There are to libraries to do this pyes and pyelasticsearch. The pyelasticsearch [website](https://github.com/rhec/pyelasticsearch) looks good, and [pyes](https://github.com/aparo/pyes/tree/master/tests) take an other approach but also is ok.

In the other hand this code works and it is very simple.

```
import urllib2 as urllib
import json
import pprint

query = {
    "from":0,
    "size":10,
    "query":{
        "field" : { 
            "name" : "david"
        }
    },
    "sort":[
        {"name":"asc"},
        {"lastName":"asc"}
    ]
}

query = json.dumps(query)
response = urllib.urlopen(
    'http://localhost:9200/users/users/_search',
    query
)

result = json.loads( response.read() )

pprint.pprint(result)
```

So I'm thinking about use the simple code instead of learn the tricks of the libraries.

Comment: this is fine ... although people typically use urllib2.urlopen ... I think it resolves some urllib issues...

Comment: @JoranBeasley, urllib2 is being used.

Comment: oh yeah... didnt notice earlier ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach of using the REST API to interface with ElasticSearch.

Pyes and the other libraries provide a wrapper around the REST API so that you can write Python code as oppose to building the JSON queries yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your code snippet as shown in your question won't work in Python 3. One has to encode the query string and also add a content header to your request. So in Python 3 do the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import json
import pprint

query = {
    "from":0,
    "size":10,
    "query":{
        "field" : { 
            "name" : "david"
        }
    },
    "sort":[
        {"name":"asc"},
        {"lastName":"asc"}
    ]
}
# encode your json string
query = json.dumps(query).encode("utf-8")
# add a content-type header
request = Request('http://localhost:9200/users/users/_search', data=query, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
response = urlopen(request)
result = json.loads( response.read() )
pprint.pprint(result)
```